# Sprite Kit stop playing music file and start from the beginning

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Whenever I present my scene, I want to start playing a music file and stop the music playing from the last time my scene was presented. I'm trying to do it like this.

```
[self removeActionForKey:@"Music"];
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Music.wav" waitForCompletion:YES]] withKey:@"Music"];
```

Should I use `AVAudioPlayer` or `[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:]`?

Also I would like to know if there is a way to play music file forever in all scenes without starting from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play background music in all scenes I will recommend `AVAudioPlayer`. You can write the code somewhere in your `AppDelegate` to access from all the scenes. Here is a sample code to achieve this using `AVAudioPlayer`

```
//    AVAudioPlayer *bgMusicLoop;

- (void)playBackroundMusic:(NSString *)fileName withExtenstion:(NSString *)fileExtension
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:fileExtension];
    NSError *error;
    if(bgMusicLoop)
        [bgMusicLoop stop];
    bgMusicLoop = nil;
    bgMusicLoop = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        bgMusicLoop.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [bgMusicLoop prepareToPlay];
        [bgMusicLoop play];
    }
}

- (void)stopBackgroundMusic
{
    if(bgMusicLoop)
        [bgMusicLoop stop];
    bgMusicLoop = nil;
}

- (void)pauseBackgroundMusic
{
    if(bgMusicLoop && bgMusicLoop.isPlaying)
        [bgMusicLoop pause];
}

- (void)resumeBackgroundMusic
{
    if(bgMusicLoop && !bgMusicLoop.isPlaying)
        [bgMusicLoop play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For music you should use `AVAudioPlayer` as using `SKAction` to play music will block any other actions you might want to run on the scene and its a bit more cumbersome to handle especially if you want to play more sounds along with the music.

Use `SKAction` to play short sound files (like player jump/fire etc...)

With `AVAudioPlayer` you can easily set your file to play repeatedly until stopped